# An interesting combinatorial problem on selecting balls

Tags: combinatorics

I did ask the similar question several months ago. But there is no right answer to it. Hence, I write down this question in detail here.

There are $n$ distinct balls. There are $p$ persons, and the $i$th person selects $q_i$ distinct balls from these $n$ distinct balls.

The question is: what is the probability that $q_0$ balls are exactly identical in every $q_i$ distinct balls which the $i$th person selects ($i = 1, 2, \dots, p$).

(Without loss of generality you may assume $q_0 \le q_1 \le q_2 \le \dots \le q_p <n$.)

**Two-person Case** This case is simple and easy. Now, we first consider this simple two-person case: there are two persons, Tom and Jack. Tom selects $q_1$ distinct balls from these $n$ distinct balls; In the same way, Jack selects $q_2$ distinct balls from these $n$ distinct balls. The probability that $q_0$ balls are exactly identical in Tom's $q_1$ balls and Jack's $q_2$ balls equals 
$${Prob}_2=\binom{n}{q_1}\binom{q_1}{q_0}\binom{n-q_1}{q_2-q_0}/\binom{n}{q_1}/\binom{n}{q_2}$$
The thought behind the formula ${Prob}_2$ is: Tom selects $q_1$ balls first. Then Jack selects $q_0$ balls from these $q_1$ balls. After that, Jack selects $q_2-q_0$ balls from the rest $n-q_1$ balls.

**More-than-two-person Case** I feel this case is difficult. I try solving it by the following thought: 
Step 1) Select $q_0$ balls from $n$ balls;
Step 2) Each person selects $q_i−q_0$ balls from the rest $n−q_0$ balls.

The formula is 
$${Prob}_p=\binom{n}{q_0}\binom{n-q_0}{q_1-q_0}\binom{n-q_0}{q_2-q_0}\binom{n-q_0}{q_3-q_0}...\binom{n-q_0}{q_p-q_0}/\binom{n}{q_1}/\binom{n}{q_2}/\binom{n}{q_3}/.../\binom{n}{q_p}$$
Unfortunately, this formula ${Prob}_p$ is wrong because ${Prob}_p \neq {Prob}_2$ when $p=2$.

Thus, the question is how to solve the general case of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it, you just need to remember that each set of $q_i - q_0$ balls has to be disjoint from each other, so you have to keep subtracting them from the next combination.  So

$$Prob_p = \frac{{n\choose q_0} {n-q_0 \choose q_1 - q_0} {n - q_0 - (q_1 - q_0) \choose q_2 - q_0} {n - q_0 - (q_1 - q_0) - (q_2 - q_0) \choose q_3 - q_0} \cdots {n - q_0 - (q_1 - q_0) - \cdots - (q_{p-1} - q_0) \choose q_p - q_0}}{{n \choose q_1} {n \choose q_2} \cdots {n \choose q_p}}$$

Comment: I have checked your formula, I believe your answer is correct, it is right when p=2 at least. Thank you very much, Deedlit!